# filter out text from a complex json object created by an ansible register of gentent module using a json_qry

Tags: ansible, jinja2, jmespath

Specifically I want a "string" of account IDs that are missing from a list I give the task on a server in my inventory.

I run the getent module in the task and I register the result which seems to be a complext JSON object with the data I want as a ket called "item" buried in an array of objects called "results" which is itself an object of "result".

I'm attempting to parse the "result" object for any key called "failed" that has a value of true and extract that object's key value for "item" which is the account id.

I need a boast to get beyond my lack of understanding.

thanks!

Nothing I've tried works. I'm not sure if it's my syntax or a lack of understanding how to parse or "interpret" the JSON object stored in "result"

I think my syntax for the qry variable is asking for any array element in results (an array of objects) which has a key called "failed" with a value of true and if a match is found, return the value of its "item" key. I know if it worked it would return a list. what I need is a string, but I haven't been able to get any result except an empty list [].

I've tried many variations, but the result is always blank.

```
 qry: "result.results[?failed == true].item"
 qry: "results[?failed == true].item"
 qry: "[?failed == true].item"
```

Here is the JSON object returned by ansible  "debug: var=result "

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [x.y.z.abc.com] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "database": "passwd",
                        "fail_key": true,
                        "key": "abc123",
                        "split": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "abc123",
                "msg": "One or more supplied key could not be found in the database."
            },
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "database": "passwd",
                        "fail_key": true,
                        "key": "pubsub",
                        "split": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "pubsub",
                "msg": "One or more supplied key could not be found in the database."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the playbook section of code:

```
- name: "Account checks"
    ignore_errors: True
    with_items:
        - abc123
        - pubsub
    getent: database=passwd key={{ item }}
    register: result
  - debug: var=result
  - debug: msg="Account id is {{ result | json_query(qry) }} "
    vars:
        qry: "result.results[?failed == true].item"
```

Here is the output of my json_qry call:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [xyz.abc.com] => {}

MSG:

Account id is
```

What I want is something like:

"Account id is abc123, pubsub"

Answer (score 0):

`result` is the top construct you are passing to `json_query` so it does not exists as top element when it starts processing the data. Moreover, checking for a field without comparison will make sure that field exists and that its value is not false.

Therefore, the correct query to get your info is: `results[?failed].item`

As you already guessed, this will return a list of `item` strings for all failed results. You just have to loop over that list to get the individual values.

Below a sample playbook. I changed one `failed` value to `false` in your sample data to illustrate.

```
---
- name: Parse result list with json_query
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    "result": {
      "changed": false,
      "failed": true,
      "msg": "All items completed",
      "results": [
      {
        "_ansible_item_result": true,
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "_ansible_parsed": true,
        "changed": false,
        "failed": true,
        "invocation": {
          "module_args": {
            "database": "passwd",
            "fail_key": true,
            "key": "abc123",
            "split": null
          }
        },
        "item": "abc123",
        "msg": "One or more supplied key could not be found in the database."
      },
      {
        "_ansible_item_result": true,
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "_ansible_parsed": true,
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "invocation": {
          "module_args": {
            "database": "passwd",
            "fail_key": true,
            "key": "pubsub",
            "split": null
          }
        },
        "item": "pubsub",
        "msg": "One or more supplied key could not be found in the database."
      }
      ]
    }

  tasks:

    - name: Get item value of failed results
      vars:
        query: results[?failed].item
      debug:
        msg: "The user id is {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ result | json_query(query) }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [Parse result list with json_query] PLAY RECAP **********************************

TASK [Get item value of failed results] PLAY RECAP ***********************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc123) => {
    "msg": "The user id is abc123"
}


PLAY RECAP ***********************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm still unclear about your statement  "...checking for a field without comparison will make sure that field exists and that its value is not false." So let's say one of the elements in this list of hashes didn't have the 'failed' key but did have the 'item' key? In that scenario would the 'item' value get returned even though no 'failed' key existed?

Comment: No it won't return anything when there is no `failed` key in the hashmap. Just copy/paste my minimal example, change the values in the example data, run it and watch the magic happen.